# Why can't I add to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which works:

```
function createTableFor(pid, numCol, numRow) {
    var p5 = document.getElementById(pid);
    var html = '<table>';

    for(var i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
      html += '<tr>';
      for(var j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
        html += `<td id="${i}-${j}"></td>`;
      }
      html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';

    p5.innerHTML += html;
  }
```

But before, instead of having a string `html` that I created the html string I used directly `p5.innerHTML`:

```
  function createTableFor(pid, numCol, numRow) {
    var p5 = document.getElementById(pid);
    p5.innerHTML += '<table>';

    for(var i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
      p5.innerHTML += '<tr>';
      for(var j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
        p5.innerHTML += `<td id="${i}-${j}"></td>`;
      }
      p5.innerHTML += '</tr>';
    }
    p5.innerHTML += '</table>';
  }
```

Which didn't work and only the `<table></table>` HTML showed up.

What I'm wondering is why didn't using `p5.innerHTML` work throughout the code and why did I have to create a separate HTML string and append that to `p5.innerHTML` at the end?